# Maps (collection) that maintains insertion Order in java

Tags: java, android, collections

I need to use Maps in Java for an Android Application. But the problem is that the list gets sorted automatically. How do I use Maps to get the data in the same order as I have inserted data.

Comment: it might be prudent to rename the title to better reflect that fact that you're interested in a map that maintains insertion order

Comment: What list gets sorted automatically? Is that a problem? or is it part of your problem *statement?* Question remains unclear.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use `LinkedHashMap` for this purpose..Visit [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

The [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) maintains insertion order.

Comment: Not only that, it's got an easy hook to build a cache out of it.  Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

A [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) will keep the data in the same order as it has been inserted.

Answer (score 2):

As you and I have discovered, LinkedHashMap isn't very helpful. (What is the point of its existence, anyway?)

I have a hashlist (semantically, I think it should have been called hashedlist)

http://code.google.com/p/synthfuljava/source/browse/trunk/gwt/util/org/synthful/gwt/util/HashList.java

It has an arraylist and a hashmap. The arraylist stores the key.

A hashlist.put(key, value) would perform

- a map.put(key, value)
- as well as a list.add(key)

A hashlist.get(int position) would perform
- a map.get(list.get(position))

This is a simplification of HashVector and HashTree classes I wrote back in 2003 when I needed to model javascript and xml objects in Java, retaining their order. However, I did not find the time or necessity to simplify the hashtree for gwt serializability.

On second thoughts, how does GWT implement a hashmap? I think when I have the time, I need to replace the hashmap with faststringmap. Google's faststringmap is not public. It is for GWT compiler private use. So you have to copy its code and change it into a public class: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FastStringMap.java

http://jectbd.com/?p=95

May be, GWT compiler would have silently used it anyway - should I bother to micromanage the compiler replace hashmap with faststringmap?

BTW,

You could still look for the hashtree by googling "googlecode synthful hashtree".

The Hashtree allows you to create a tree of objects and allows you to retrieve your objects using the an dot-convention xpath like path.

```
hashtree.get("hello.dolly.how.are.you");
```

The separator could be respecified so that you could store or get using

```
hashtree.get("hello/dolly/how/are/you");
hashtree.put("hello/dolly/how/are/you", value);
```

Comment: It does seem you don't understand the purpose of LinkedHashMap, what where you expecting of it?

Comment: Genuinely curious, what aspect of a LinkedHashMap makes it inadequate for the OP's purpose?

Comment: linkedhashmap.insert(6, key, value)? linkedhashmap.remove(7)? linkedhashmap.put(20, key, value)? It does appear I don't understand the purpose of MS windows when I could use Linux.

Comment: @BlessedGeek but that's not needed to answer the question. So LinkedHashMap is perfectly helpful. Usually a bike will suffice, even if you own a proper German car.

Answer (score 1):

use `LinkedHashMap`. [please follow this link for more details](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ313_025.htm)